# Passing stateful lambda into C style function without context-argument

Tags: c++, lambda, function-pointers

I'm trying to integrate a C library into my C++ project. The C library has functions which take function pointers as arguments but these function pointers are written as typedefs.

```
typedef void(*FileHandler_t)(File* handle);
```

Then a function to register the callback like so:

```
void RegisterCallback(FileHandler_t handler);
```

I can create a lambda expression and pass that into RegisterCallback for the argument handler

```
auto handler = [](File* handle){ //handle cb };
```

And this works fine.

```
RegisterCallback(handler);
```

But when I try to pass local variables to be used inside the handler I receive compiler errors.

```
auto handler = [&container](File* handle){ //handle cb };
```

Now RegisterCallback no longer compiles.
I wanted to do it this way because I didn't want to use global variables. Is there anyway around the error which is formally used in these scenarios?

From what I can see, there's no way around this other than either modifying the library itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, designers of C libraries that use callbacks like this provide some way to associate a state variable to the callback. Often a `void*` argument. Some libraries take that state pointer when you pass the callback, and pass the pointer to the callback function, e.g. WinAPI usually does that, see [EnumWindows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows). Other libraries allow to place that thing into some object they’re passing to the callback, e.g. libpng does that with `png_set_write_fn` and `png_get_io_ptr` API functions.

If after reading available documentation you concluded that’s not the case for your library, and you can’t or don’t want to ask library author for support, this means you have to be more creative.

One workaround is using a hash map to associate files with containers. Like this:

```
static std::unordered_map<File*, Container*> s_containers;
```

Associate the file with container before `RegisterCallback`, and in the callback, lookup by file pointer to find out the container. Think about threading, maybe you need to guard that static hash map with a mutex. Also think about exception handling, maybe you need RAII class to register in constructor/unregister in destructor.

Another, much simpler but more limited method, is using thread_local storage class specifier introduced in C++/11, declare

```
static thread_local Container* s_container;
```

And use it in the callback. If your library does blocking IO and doesn’t internally use threading, there’s a good chance this will work OK. But still you need to handle errors, i.e. reset the global variable to `nullptr` when container goes out of scope.

**Update:** If you can change the library, doing so is much better than both workarounds. Pass one more `void*` argument to RegisterCallback, and change handler to `typedef void(*FileHandler_t)(File* handle, void* context);` If you’re consuming the library from C++, it’s usually good idea to implement the callback as private static method, and pass `this` pointer into the library. This will allow you to call instance methods in the callback while keeping internal state of your class hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Lambdas normally have a type you can't rely on; only in the case that they don't capture anything, does the type "[decay to](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150220-00/?p=44623/)" (equal) a function pointer.

The most common workaround is to use static data in the lambda instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef void(*FuncInt)(int);

static bool DataTheFunctionNeeds = true;

int main() {
    FuncInt a = [](int) { };
    FuncInt b = [](int) { if(DataTheFunctionNeeds){} };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, there is no `void*` pointer which is normaly used for identification in the callback function.

However, **as a workaround** you could introduce a class template which stores this information for you. [live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cff689c0b2a3223a):

```
template<typename FN>
class dispatcher {
    static inline std::function<void(int)> fn_;

    static void foo(int x) { fn_(x); }

public:
    static fn_type dispatch(FN fn) {
        fn_ = fn;
        return &dispatcher::foo;
    }
};
```

The class is a template for the purpose to resolve the ambiguity of the member function `fn_`.

This won't work very well with classes, though. But you can change it so that you provide some sort of own "disambiguiteer". [live demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d73f93aa89926517):

```
template<int DSP>
class dispatcher {
    static inline std::function<void(int)> fn_;

    static void foo(int x) { fn_(x); }

public:
    template<typename FN>
    static fn_type dispatch(FN fn) {
        fn_ = fn;
        return &dispatcher::foo;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the lambda has state, the conversion of such a lambda to function pointer would involve storing the lambda state in variables with static storage duration.

This is obviously error prone, because, at each conversion to function pointer, the static storage duration state would be modified leading to very difficult to track errors. This is certainly the reason why lambda with state cannot be converted to function pointer.

On the other hand, if you understand what is the danger, you can implement  static storage duration lambda conversion. (you must be sure that after a conversion to function pointer, the previously converted lambda instance is not accessed):

```
#include <utility>
#include <new>

//bellow, a more efficient version of std::function
//for holding (statically) typed lambda of static storage duration
//Because lamda type depends on the function in which they are defined
//this is much more safer than a naive implementation using std::function.
template<class LT>
struct static_lambda{
  private:
    static inline unsigned char buff alignas(LT) [sizeof(LT)];
    static inline LT* p=nullptr;
    static inline struct raii_guard{
      ~raii_guard(){
         if (p) p->~LT();
         }
      } guard{};
  public:
    static_lambda(LT g_){
       if (p) p->~LT();
       p=new (buff) LT{std::move(g_)};
       }

    static_lambda(const static_lambda&)=delete //for safety

    template<class...Args>
    static auto execute(Args...args){
      return (*p)(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
      }
    template<class FT>
    operator FT*() && {//by rvalue reference for safety reason
      return execute;
      }
  };


using File = int;
typedef void(*FileHandler_t)(File* handle);
void RegisterCallback(FileHandler_t handler);

using container_type=double*;

void test(container_type& container){
  //each time this function is called
  //the previously registered lambda is destroyed
  //and should not be accessed (which is certainly the case).
  RegisterCallback(static_lambda{[&container](File* h){}});
  }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vFIoKA)